# How to override name of parent properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

There is parent project with additional module that I have to use in my project, it looks like this:

```
microservice-template
    microservice-parent
    microservice-jpa (it has application-jpa.properties file for config)
    microservice-jdbc
    microservice-abc
```

Now in my project I set parent of my main pom to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bla.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

and in dependencies I want to use microservice-jpa

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bla.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is, when I want to run tests in my project and use standard name **application-test.properties** then my project does not override **application-jpa.properties** from this microservice-jpa dependency. Properties are overrided only if I set my file to same name application-jpa.properties which looks weird in tests. How can I tell spring boot that I want to override properties from parent but with different file name?